# How can I stop the timer permanently based on the user IP address?

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer

I want to integrate the below ip based code in my given snippet example. The thing that I want is that the timer got freeze  when it is for same ip.

This below code is used to identify the user pc ip.

```
$.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json", function(e) {
    console.log(e.ip);
});
```

I want to freeze the below timer on the bases of above ip for single single user

```js
$(function() {
  $('#ms_timer').countdowntimer({
    minutes: 00,
    seconds: 05,
    size: "lg",
    timeUp: () => console.log("Hello")
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/jquery.countdownTimer.min.js"></script>
<span id="ms_timer" class="d-block mb-2"></span>
```

How can I achieve that by jquery?

Comment: Your question is not very clear. you are using an api to get public ip address of your own system. Now you want to match that ip address (returned from api) with your own ip address?

Comment: @LilFlower see the edit. please let me know it any doubt here.

Comment: You want the timer to not run if its alreayd being ran from the same IP? Meaning you want run timer once only for each user IP ? Correct

Comment: @AlwaysHelping yes you are right!

Comment: What if the user refreshes the page ? Are you open to using localStorage to store the IP in the browser to only run once.

Comment: yeah I can store but how I will stop the timer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [localStorage](https://www.google.com/search?q=local%20storae&oq=local%20storae&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l6j69i60.3407j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) to achieve your desired results. `localStorage` works off each browser.

Firstly, we need to store the `IP` of user on first page and run the timer first time for user. If the user `refreshes` the page a message will `popup` saying that the timer `already` ran for this `IP` address.

We are checking the stored `IP` address with the `current` IP and if matches we do not run the timer and show OR else we run the timer if the IP is `unique`.

**Live Demo:** (You need to use own browser for this demo to work as localStorage does not work in stack snippets.)

```js
$(function() {

  let currUserIP
  $.getJSON("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json", function(e) {
    currUserIP = e.ip //set variable
    checkCounter() //check counter
  });

  //get user IP and check if its matches
  function checkCounter() {
    let getUserIp = localStorage.getItem('setUserIP'); //get loca storage
    if (getUserIp != currUserIP) {
      $('#ms_timer').countdowntimer({
        minutes: 00,
        seconds: 05,
        size: "lg",
        timeUp: function() {
          localStorage.setItem('setUserIP', currUserIP);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $('#ms_timer').text('The timer ran already from this IP')
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://harshen.github.io/jquery-countdownTimer/jquery.countdownTimer.min.js"></script>
<span id="ms_timer" class="d-block mb-2"></span>
```

Comment: yeah this is fine but one thing is there when ever I'm refreshing the page while the count is decreasing then it again starts from the `5`. Means if I refresh the page when the count is `3` then it will again start from `5`. Is there anything to stop this?

Comment: @PuneetJindal No thats not possible. Because the seconds and time comes from library you are using. It will restart again once the page is refresh in the middle. Would you mind accepting the answer if i have solved the original question and have provided a solution to that ? Thanks :)